# La phrase entre le titre et le texte, comment s'appelle-t-elle ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Dans un article ou le début d'un chapitre d'un livre, comment s'appelle la phrase qui se place entre le titre et le texte ? La phrase "Ah, la recherche. Du temps perdu." dans [cet article](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-2/fulltext.pdf) en est exemple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une [épigraphe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pigraphe)<sup>1</sup> parfois aussi appelé [exergue](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exergue)<sup>2</sup> :

> 1 : Citation placée en tête d'un écrit pour en suggérer le sujet ou l'esprit.
>
> 2 : Formule, pensée, citation placée en tête d'un écrit pour en résumer le sens, l'esprit, la portée

Voir aussi [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pigraphe_(litt%C3%A9rature))